# Android Media Player Selective Looping of MP3

Tags: android, mp3, media-player

Is this possible? In my specific app, the soundtrack has an intro which should only be played once when the app is launched. The music will then transition into the 'main track' (it's all one MP3 of course), but when the track ends, it should only loop back to the point when the intro ended - ie, not play the intro again.

A more common example would be a normal song that starts at the intro, then plays the song, then loops the chorus at the end to fade.......

I can only find a way to set the actual loop to on or off -

```
musicPlayer.setLooping(true); //No way to set loop points?!
```

In the below diagram the loop is represented by the dotted line.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Why not split in two mp3 files?

Comment: Yes @Luiz but what I'm asking is how do I do this seamlessly? I.e., detect that one has finished so I can start the other?

Comment: If you have two separate files of mp3, one with intro and another with main track, what you need to do is set OnCompletionListener for the intro mp3 and when it finish, you start the main track. http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener.html

Comment: I see, I didn't think of that - I'll look into it - thanks!

Comment: Ok, if you need help with that approach, let me know. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Create a helper method to get the `startingPosition` of the main track and `seekTo()` that position after the whole track(intro + main) ends.
Use a **flag** to know that whether is it the first time or not. If not, loop back to the obtained seek position.

```
     public int getMainAudioStartingPosition() {
           // position value in int.
           return MAIN_AUDIO_STARTING_POSITION;
     }
```

Create another method to playMedia which takes the `startPosition` as an input param. Call this method on completion of the entire audio file and everytime it gets called, it will loopback to the starting position of the Main audio whatsoever it shall be.

```
    public void playMedia(int startPos) {
        startPos = startPos * 1000;
        mMediaPlayer.seekTo(startPos);
        isAlreadyPlayed = true;
        mMediaPlayer.start();
    }
```

so your `onCompletionListener` will look something like this.

```
        // register onCompletionListener for looping back
        mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                // if this is already played then start from starting pos of Main audio
                if (isAlreadyPlayed) {
                    playMedia(getMainAudioStartingPosition());
                }
            }
        });
```

This way you can set up the loop by using `onCompletionListener` and playing the media file again and again.

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: Hi @PavitraKansara, thanks, this does work, but this (and any other method I use when starting any media player from within onCompletion), results in a slight delay before the loop re-starts - it's about maybe a 1/2 second delay but it sounds horrible and isn't a smooth transition between loops.

Answer (score 0):

You can't loop audio smoothly without using C++ library such [SuperPowered](https://SuperPowered.com) or JUCE